# Gwt + Spring Security integration

Tags: security, hibernate, spring, gwt, aspectj

I'm building an application with **(smart)gwt**, **hibernate** (actually **gilead**, or **hibernate4gwt**) and **Spring Security**.

I'm pretty new to all of these, by the way.

Everything worked fine until now, but I've recently added Spring security functionality, in order to implement an authentication system. Seems there are multiple ways of making this work, I looked at a few tutorials.

I liked this simple idea here: http://blog.maxmatveev.com/2011/06/gwt-and-spring-security-integration-as.html?showComment=1328698687249#c4823182825437196300

I also tried this one (a lot of dummy classes and such, but oh well): http://seewah.blogspot.com/2009/02/gwt-and-spring-security.html

In both cases I have the same problem, I get this error in the applicationContext.xml:

```
Error occured processing XML 'org/springframework/security/access/intercept/aopalliance/MethodSecurityInterceptor'
```

In the first link it occurs at line:

```
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" mode="aspectj"/>
```

In the second link it occurs at line:

```
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" jsr250-annotations="disabled" />
```

I googled the problem, but I didn't find an answer..

**PS1:** using Eclipse 3.6, and I have installed plugins for **Spring framework** and **aspectJ**.

**PS2:** I didn't write all the code here, instead I liked to the tutorials i used (would have been too much code).

Maybe someone can help me out.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a problem with version of Spring/Spring Security.

Make sure you are updated to recent version (to handle attribute `mode="aspectj"` of element `security:global-method-security`) e.g. Spring-Security 3.1.